# How to manipulate long style from inkscape

Tags: javascript, svg, inkscape, setattribute

I Place a svg (Inkscape picture) in an **object** tag like this

```
<div class='rbis-svg-row'>
   <div class='rbis-salta-svg'>
      <object id='svg1'  data='factory4-network-salta.svg' type='image/svg+xml' width='900px'>
    </object>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I can then access the elements in the svg with

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("svg1").addEventListener("load", function() {
       var doc = this.getSVGDocument();
        var rect = doc.querySelector('#rectABC'); 
        // Id for an object is rectABC                                                                                               

        var theStyle = reg.getAttribute('style');

     });

</script>
```

BUT!

The style is quite long

```
"color:#000000;cliprule:nonzero;display:inline;overflow:visible;\
 visibility:visible;opacity:0.58999999;isolation:auto;\
 mix-blend mode:normal;colorinterpolation:sRGB;\
 color-interpolationfilters:linearRGB;solid-color:#000000;\
 solid-opacity:1;fill:#fcaf3e;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;\
 stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3;stroke-linecap:round;\
 stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;\
 stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;\
 marker:none;color-rendering:auto;image-rendering:auto;\
 shape-rendering:auto;text-rendering:auto;enable-background:accumulate"
```

Is there any good way to change a **single** property in the style? Or must I
extract the string and manipulate the string?

/gh

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same method as you would for HTML.

```
element.style.fill = "red";
```

Not that style properties in the `style` object do not always have the same name as the XML attribute. If the attribute has a hyphen, then the property will have camel-case naming.  For example, the `fill-opacity` attribute can be changed with:

```
element.style.fillOpacity = 1;
```